# When using Django save() to update db, exception is thrown but why is db still updated?

Tags: python, django, database

Here is my models and views file. My objective was to add a new attribute to my db ("Entries") which I added to my models and make the migrations using the python manage.py commands. That worked and everything had the new attribute with the correct default "NA" in it. I then wanted to read a file and use that column to update the db with the correct values. It "worked" except that after the .save() command was executed it updated the db correctly but still threw my exception error and left the try block.

I tried searching to see if someone else had the same issue and read through the documentation on django's site about save()
[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/]

I was wondering why and if anyone else has had this issue and can tell me what to do in the future to fix this problem.

The way I know my db was updated was afterwards I ran a "Data.objects.all()" and on each one printed out the "Probes" and "Entries" to see that they all changed from NA to what my file was.

Thanks for any help.

models.py

```
class Data(models.Model):
    Probes = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    Entries = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="NA")
    Symbol = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Pattern = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    Day1 = models.FloatField()
    Day3 = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('Probes', 'Symbol', 'Pattern'),)
```

views.py

```
def testUpdateDB(passFileName):

f = open(passFileName, 'r')

for Line in f:
    Line = Line.replace('\r',"")
    Line = Line.replace('\n', "")

    row = Line.split(",")

    AryList = {"Probes": row[0],
               "Entries":row[2],
               "Symbol": row[3],
               "Pattern":row[4],
               "Day1":   row[5],
               "Day3":   row[6]
               }
    try:
        # Update the database
        t = Data.objects.get(Probes=AryList["Probes"])

        print(t.Probes + " has " + t.Entries + " for its entries, updating to " + AryList["Entries"])

        t.Entries = AryList["Entries"]
        t.save()

        u = Data.objects.get(Probes=AryList["Probes"])

        print(u.Probes + " has " + u.Entries + " for its entries now. Update was sussess!")

    except:
        print("Could not find: " + AryList["Probes"])
```

In my views.py right after/during the "t.save()" the program skips to the exception block and prints out that message. Afterwards I can look at the db and see that everything was updated correctly, but then why did the exception happen? Also why didn't the entire try block finish? Anyone else have this error when trying to update their database.

Comment: Why do you bring `u`? You already have the object in `t`

Comment: **Never, ever** do a blank `except`. You have six lines inside that try block, and the exception could be caused by any of them; the likelihood here is that you have some other (probably trivial) error. If you want to just catch the exception when the Data does not exist, catch that only: `except Data.DoesNotExist:`.

Comment: Patito, when I was debugging I thought it was the t so I tried assigning the query result to a new var, and just never changed it back.

Comment: Daniel, I originally had a print statement after each line ie: print("Before save") ... print("After save") ... and once I narrowed it down to the "t.save()" causing the error I took them out to post the question. So I'm sure its that line causing it to go to the exception. I'm just not sure why, or why it throws the exception but yet still updates the db?

Comment: Again, **anything** could be happening inside that save call, and we don't know what, because you've hidden the error by catching it with that blank except. If the error is not a DoesNotExist, then you shouldn't catch it *at all*; remove the try and except altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [transaction.atomic()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly) if any error occurs all the code present within the block will be rolled back. Nothing will be saved unless the whole block executes.

It is well documented with examples in link above, try to use all the save() inside atomic transaction.

Comment: make sure you set ```ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True``` in your settings when use transaction.atomic()

Comment: @luke_aus `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` does the exact same thing as `transaction.atomic()`, why would you need it when you provide more granular transaction control with `atomic()` already?

Answer (score 0):

The header record was causing the issue. Once discarding the first record of the file everything worked great.

Here is the updated Views.py file

views.py

```
def testUpdateDB(passFileName):

    f = open(passFileName, 'r')

    discardHeader = f.readline() # New line which removes header record

    for Line in f:
        # Everything else stay the same as before #
```

Thanks to everyone for helping out.